# print(..., end=' ') with immediate output

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, io

I need a piece of Python code that loads (stresses?) CPU for a short moment. I would also like to get some output like counter printed during stressing CPU. Seems simple enough:

```
N=32

def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


def main(num):
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        fib(N)
        print(i, end=' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(10)
```

However, when I use `print(i, end=' ')`, it does not output counter as it executes, it only outputs `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` once it completes.

If I use regular print (`print(i)`) it prints the counter as it goes.

First of all, I want to know why this weird effect takes place, and second, how to make `print` with `end` behave in this regard like `print` without `end` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` operation is buffered by default, but you can force it to flush the buffer and print immediately. See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more info.

```
print("foobar", flush=True)
```